# Make scrollbar slider RIGHT TO LEFT

Tags: jquery, slide

Good Day,

First: i can't speak english very well

I want to create a schrollbar that slides div from right to left.

I use this Slider: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-jquery-slider-to-scroll-a-div

I set the Script from:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#content-slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    change: handleSliderChange,
    slide: handleSliderSlide
  });
});
```

To:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#content-slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    change: handleSliderChange,
    slide: handleSliderSlide,
    value: 1000
  });
});
```

Now the Handler from the Scrollbar is on the right side, but the Divs are allways on the left side:

> German = English links = left mitte = middle

http://s1.directupload.net/images/121109/678f8ov8.png

I want that the divs start with the last divs!

You know what i mean

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the main things you will need are `value` here

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#content-slider").slider({
     animate: true,
     change: handleSliderChange,
     slide: handleSliderSlide,
     value: $("#content-scroll").width()
   });
 });
```

and initializing the container already scrolled to the right with

`$("#content-scroll").animate({scrollLeft: 
      ($("#content-scroll").width()) }, 0);`

A full working example can be seen here http://jsbin.com/onodij/1/edit

If that isn't quite what you are looking for, add a version of your code on jsbin or jsfiddle and I'll take a look at it.